# Is it possible to update my environment with environment.yml Anaconda Navigator with the 'Import environment' menu option?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I know how to update my environment via command-line, but I would like to perform the same operation through Anaconda Navigator (web interface).

In Anaconda Navigator there is some menu option such as 'New environment', etc, etc, but I do not see 'Update existing environment'. I saw the 'Import environment' option using an environment YAML file. This is exactly what I would like to have, but for my use case 'Update existing environment'.

Can I use the 'Import environment' option in Navigator and expect that Navigator intelligently detects that it should perform an update and NOT an import (thus not trying to recreate the same environment again)?